# Flutter How to converting Map<dynamic, dynamic> from Hive box to Map<String, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I have a Hive box to save a `Map<String, dynamic>` using `toJson()`. But when I retrieve it, the result are a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`, I've tried converting it using `jsonDecode()`, but not working. I also have tried converting it to *String* first then wrapping it up with `jsonEncode()` then `jsonDecode()`, still not working.

PS: Datatype other than a *Map* does work without problem

```dart
final HiveHelper hh = HiveHelper();
final box = Hive.openBox('boxip');
...
...
Future<void> saveDataIp(Map<String, dynamic> ip) async {
    await hh.saveToBox(box, 'ip', ip);
}
...
Map<String, dynamic> getDataIp() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    // ip resulting a _Map<dynamic, dynamic>
    final ip = hh.getFrombox(box, 'ip');
    if (ip != null) {
      // with only using jsonDecode() gives error type "'_Map<dynamic, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'"
      // below gives error "Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'"
      map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(ip)));
    }
    return map;
  }
...
...
...
final data = Data(id: 1, name: "item", date: "2023-07-17T10:45:40.070Z");
await saveDataIp(data.toJson());
final dataBox = getDataIp();
```

Comment: Can you share the response that you are getting from this hh.getFrombox(box, 'ip') ?

Comment: `print(ip)` returns `{id: 1, name: item, date: 2023-07-17T10:45:40.070Z}` with type __Map<dynamic, dynamic>_, thats why when I'm going to convert it with `Map.from()` gives error "...is not a subtype ..."

Comment: and on line `map = Map.from()` it gives error `Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'`

Comment: I'm sorry if its not clear, I'm still working on this too, thats why there's some missunderstanding error message I've posted

Comment: can you share the output for this statement :  jsonEncode(ip)

Comment: error Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'

Answer (score 1):

First, here are 2 types to get a cleaner code and get less lost in your code:

- type your variables
- use an analysis_options.yaml with linter rules

I'm not sure to understand what is your problem.

If I summarise:

- you create an obejct with type Data
- you transform it to json => type Map<String, dynamic>
- you save it into a hiveBox
- you get it back with getFrombox() under Map<String, dynamic> type

then what do you need to do? You can add a fromMap() method in your Data class to parse your box result back into Data type.

Also why don't you use directly box.save() and box.get()?

Comment: because I've created HiveHelper as a _singleton Class_ so that I can call it for other datatype, like _String_, _int_, _bool_. And those type work flawlsessly, I can do stuff with it but with _Map_ that contain a _DateTime_ always gives error.

Comment: Actually, the _Data_ is to save an API respon, then being parsed to other screen with addition element that not necessary to be saved. Thats why I need to retrieve as _Map_

Answer (score 0):

data.dart:

```js
import 'dart:convert';

class Data {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final DateTime date;

  Data({required this.id, required this.name, required this.date});

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'id': id,
      'name': name,
      'date': date.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
    };
  }

  factory Data.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Data(
      id: map['id'] as int,
      name: map['name'] as String,
      date: DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(map['date'] as int),
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory Data.fromJson(String source) =>
      Data.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);
}
```

Then:

```js
Future<void> saveDataIp(Data data) async {
    await hh.saveToBox(box, 'ip', data.toMap());
}
```

```js
Data getDataIp() {
    Map<String, dynamic> map = {};
    // ip resulting a _Map<dynamic, dynamic>
    final Map<String, dynamic>? dataMap = hh.getFrombox(box, 'ip');
    if (ip == null) {
      throw Exception('No ip found in the hiveBox');
    }
    return Data.fromMap(dataMap);
  }
```

And:

```js
final Data dataToSave = Data(id: 1, name: "item", date: DateTime.parse("2023-07-17T10:45:40.070Z");

await saveDataIp(data);

final Data dataRead = getDataIp();
```

let me know if it answers your need

Comment: the requirements is the `date` is _DateTime_ not an _int_ from `DateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch`. Thats why it gives error `Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'DateTime'` when I try to convert it

Comment: It's just using the int in the hive but, when you get the data from the hive, the fromMap will parse it into a DateTime don't worry